# HTML form will not submit in IE or Firefox

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having a strange issue with my HTML (or PHP) code on my web site. I'm pretty new to HTML and PHP (I'm more .NET).

On all forms on my website, the forms fail to submit in IE or Firefox. However, they work absolutely fine in Chrome (all platforms) and Safari (only tested on iPad/iPhone).

I could post the code if required, however, the issue is on my live website. Here are the forms which are immediately accessible via the homepage which have the same issue.

https://trentdiscos.co.uk/contact.php

https://trentdiscos.co.uk/login.php

All you have to do is click the submit button without entering any data. You should get an error message when the form is submitted which is returned using some simple PHP code.

If the full PHP code helps then I'm happy to post it. However, it appears to be a posting issue to me.

I can also replicate this issue on a local Apache web server.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: your page is working fine

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: yeah on firefox errors don't appear

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: working fine in IE also

Comment: Try with defining action as `action="contact.php"` in your form. Some browsers may behave different when your form action is empty.

Comment: can you please post code?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, this should be fine as per the [HTML Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1). Type image should act as a submit button.

In the below line:

```
<input name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" src="submit.png" alt="Submit" type="image">
```

If you change `type="image"` to:

```
type="submit"
```

It shows the error as you wanted. However, I can't say for certain what the problem is without seeing the whole of the code.